# Spark SQL | Any depth path ($..foo) not working with get_json_object

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following code sample should ideally return the value of property `value` but instead returns `null`. Is this expected? From the spark documentation, it seems any depth query is supported by spark sql and the [spark test suite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f12793de205a46c75529ac20649e2e61edc0b144/sql/catalyst/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/JsonExpressionsSuite.scala) has an example, but unfortunately its for a negative test case.

```scala
spark.sql("""select get_json_object('{"node":{"value":"abc"}}', '$..value') as j""").show()
```

Expected output - `abc` / Actual - `null`

I'm trying the any depth path because the json column in every row in the dataset has a variable schema and we're searching for a given key, say `foobar`, anywhere in the given json, so in the above example, `$.value` or `$.foo.value` for more nested values isn't something that's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_json_object` does not support recursive paths as the [test](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f12793de205a46c75529ac20649e2e61edc0b144/sql/catalyst/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/JsonExpressionsSuite.scala#L219) show it, so you can't use it in this particular case.
If you know the schema of you json string then I'd recommend you to use `from_json` function to convert it into a struct type which would be easier to handle.

However, you can always try using `regexp_extract` with some regex like:

```regex
"key"\s?:\s?"([\w\s]+)"
```

Example:

```scala
spark.sql("""
  SELECT regexp_extract('{"node":{"value":"abc"}}', '"value"\\s?:\\s?"([\\w\\s]+)"', 1) AS value
""").show()

//+-----+
//|value|
//+-----+
//|  abc|
//+-----+
```